# Multiple Count Summaries in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Database Table of Jobs. 
Each Job was created by a User. There are many users.
The User Table contains the user_id and the users email address.

```
---------------
**JOBS_TABLE**
---------------
JOB_ID
USER_ID
---------------

---------------
**USERS_TABLE**
---------------
USER_ID
USER_EMAIL
---------------
```

I want to know how many Jobs each user has created. Is it possible to do this in just SQL?

Ideally I would like the results like this.

```
------------------------------
|USER_ID|JOB_COUNT|USER_EMAIL|
------------------------------
|user1  |2000     |x@sfd.com |
|user2  |5433     |sd@fds.com|
------------------------------
```

This is once off report so I am not worried about performance. I am using MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT u.user_id,u.user_email,count(j.job_id) as jobcount FROM `users` u join jobs j on u.user_id=j.user_id group by u.user_id

This query will output as follows:

user_id    user_email      jobcount
 1           123@abc.com        3
 2         456@def.com     1

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard count query (user LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN if you want all even if they don't have a job record):

```
SELECT
  U.USER_ID,
  COUNT(JOB_ID) AS JOB_COUNT,
  U.USER_EMAIL
FROM
  USERS_TABLE U

  INNER JOIN JOBS_TABLE J ON
  U.USER_ID = J.USER_ID
GROUP BY
  U.USER_ID,
  U.USER_EMAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select user.USER_ID,user.USER_EMAIL,count(distinct jobs.JOB_ID) 
from USERS_TABLE user natural join JOBS_TABLE jobs group by user.USER_ID
```